# how can i create a map when i hover the Geographical region it comes like Comments box.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]

[image]

I want to create a map. When we look in the map there are no countries appears. But only Geographical Regions only. When you hover one of the region it will appear comment box. In the comment box, there are the countries of the region. And when we click a country we want to link the country name to a page..

Can anyone please tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Leaflet JS API provides the ability to select the map tile set you want to use, and then define multiple polygon layers that you can use to define the clickable areas/regions on the map. It features a built in pop-up system that you can populate with whatever data you want.

Short of that, you could create your map, add it as a DIV background and then create an image map of polygons to assign click handlers to.

In HTML it would look something like (where the values are X,Y position pairs for the nodes of the polygon):

```
    <area href="#" shape="poly" coords="217,305,218,306,218,306,228,316,243,316,243,
325,229,325,229,322, 217,310" alt="Some Region" title="This is the description">
```

Personally, I would recommend Leaflet as you will have a lot me built in control.

Comment: Can you tell a link to study this.??

Comment: The best place to start is the Leaflet docs. It is really well documented. Beyond that, there are tons of tutorials about how to use the API.